# redux state not updating after action complete

Tags: reactjs, redux

**Hello! my problem is my state is not uploading, is always empty altough my actions brings data correct. Can anyone give me some help of what am I doing wrong ?
I think is something with the name or the combine reducers part. 
Maybe I am not accesing data correct with my reducer or something like that **
The object I receive from the api call has this format `{categories: Array(4), items: Array(50)}`

**Component**

```
    import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
    import ItemList from '../components/ItemList/ItemList';
    import { getItems } from './actions'
    class ItemListContainer extends PureComponent {

      async componentDidMount() {
        const { getItems } = this.props;
        await getItems()

        console.log(this.props)
      }

      render() {
        return <ItemList />;
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => (
      {
      items: state.items.items,
    });

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
      bindActionCreators(
        {
          getItems,
        },
        dispatch,
      );

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ItemListContainer);
```

actions.js

```
export const GET_ITEMS = 'GET_ITEMS';
export const GET_ITEM = 'GET_ITEM';
export const GET_ITEM_DESCRIPTION = 'GET_ITEM_DESCRIPTION';

export function getItems(query) {
    return async function (dispatch) {
        // const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/items?q=${query}`)
        const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/items?q=ipad`)
        const items = await res.json()
        return dispatch({
            type: 'GET_ITEMS',
            items: items.items,
        })
    }
}
```

reducer.js

```
import { GET_ITEMS } from './actions';

const initialState = {
  items: [],
  itemsLoaded: false,
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, data } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: data,
        itemsLoaded: true,
      };
    default: {
      return {
        ...state
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was accessing { data} in the reducer which of course it was empty. The correnct action was items.

Comment: yes you need to change this 
   const { type, data } = action;
to 
  const { type, items} = action;